# Iterate through list and add dictionary value if list item is in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

I would appreciate help with the following problem from my python course

You would like to count the number of fruits in your basket. In order to do this, you have the following dictionary and list of fruits.  Use the dictionary and list to count the total number of fruits, but you do not want to count the other items in your basket.

I tried to use two for loops to solve the problem:

```
result = 0
basket_items = {'apples': 4, 'oranges': 19, 'kites': 3, 'sandwiches': 8}
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'peaches', 'grapes', 'bananas']

for fruit in fruits:
 for key, value in basket_items.items():
    result+=1
 else: result+=0

print(result)
```

My code results in 24 but the right answer is 23

Comment: You're never actually checking if key and fruit match, you get 24 because you are iterating over the entire basket (4) x fruits (6). You're never using the values, just counting everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option might be:

```py
result = 0
for key, value in basket_items.items():
    if key in fruits:
        result += value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict.get`

**Ex:**

```
result = 0
basket_items = {'apples': 4, 'oranges': 19, 'kites': 3, 'sandwiches': 8}
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'peaches', 'grapes', 'bananas']

for fruit in fruits:                       #Iterate each element in list
    result += basket_items.get(fruit, 0)   #Add to result. 

print(result)  # --> 23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = 0
basket_items = {'apples': 4, 'oranges': 19, 'kites': 3, 'sandwiches': 8}
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'peaches', 'grapes', 'bananas']

for key, value in basket_items.items():
    if key in fruits:
        result+= value
```